# cannot unmount usb hdd "unknown error" Windows 10 (fsutil claims it is built in)

Tags: windows-10, usb, usb-storage, usb-3

USB HDD connected via USB 3.0 cannot be safely removed after accessing it once (starting and stopping a VM stored on the disk). Only workaround so far is rebooting the computer.

"Das Gerät kann aufgrund eines unbekannten Fehlers nicht entfernt werden."
(device cannot be removed due to an unknown error)

- listed twice in explorer: once under "This Computer", once below that.
- right click on the drive in explorer does not display unmount option
- does not matter if it´s already plugged in to the computer when booting or not
- indexing is disabled

USB Safely Remove detects three processes accessing the drive:

1. System
2. svchost.exe
3. vmms.exe (a part of Hyper-V I think)

´fsutil fsinfo drivetype x:´ shows the drive as built in. (Just rebooted and plugged it in after boot; still the same)

Stopping vmms removes vmms from the list, but how can I stop the System (and the services host) from accessing the drive without rebooting?

Comment: You can't. It has always been an issue with Windows. Some service still has open handles on the drive. I have encountered it many times, traced all the open handles. Only option is to reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I can!

- in *computer management* > *drive management* right click the drive, open *properties*, select the drive there and click the other *properties* button, go to *guidelines* tab (or directives? what is the official term? I only know the german one *Richtlinien*) switch from *fast removal* to *improved performance*
- in services.msc: stop Hyper-V management, supervision of distributed links ("Überwachung verteilter Verknüpfungen", switch it to manual), any Backup Software and the Windows Media Player
- in Explorer: right click the drive, disable indexing
- try unmounting
- in case it still fails, deactivate your antivirus for a minute

fsinfo still identifies the drive as built in, but it can be unmounted via the system tray.

---

This is where I found the solution: http://www.drwindows.de/windows-7-allgemein/66125-externe-festplatte-laesst-entfernen.html (German)